# Django URL Order matching query does not exist

Tags: django

I'm integrating an app into an existing project and am receiving the error "Order matching query does not exist" when uncommenting a url in the app.

Here is my url page:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^', include('merged.catalog.urls')),
    # (r'^cart/', include('merged.cart.urls')),
    # (r'^checkout/', include('merged.checkout.urls')),
    (r'^accounts/', include('merged.accounts.urls')),
    (r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),    
    )
```

The site works fine with these two lines commented out, then throws an error when either one is uncommented.

The error occurs in the base.html template file. Specifically on {% url 'home' %}. If this is made into an absolute url, then the next line referencing a url name throws an error.

```
<li class="menu-tab"><a {% if request.path == '/' %}class="active"{% endif %} href="{% url "home" %}">Home</a></li>
```

I can't find anything in the url files that might throw the error:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('merged.cart.views',
    (r'^$','show_cart', {'template_name': 'cart/cart.html'}, 'show_cart'),
)
```

I don't see what would trigger the error in my view either.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from merged.cart import cart
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from merged.checkout import checkout

def show_cart(request, template_name="cart/cart.html"):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Remove':
            cart.remove_from_cart(request)
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Update':
            cart.update_cart(request)
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Checkout':
            checkout_url = checkout.get_checkout_url(request)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(checkout_url)
    cart_items = cart.get_cart_items(request)
    page_title = 'Shopping Cart'
    cart_subtotal = cart.cart_subtotal(request)
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my checkout urls page:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('merged.checkout.views',
    (r'^$', 'show_checkout', {'template_name': 'checkout/checkout.html'}, 'checkout'),
    (r'^receipt/$', 'receipt', {'template_name': 'checkout/receipt.html'}, 'checkout_receipt'),
)
```

My Checkout View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from merged.checkout.forms import CheckoutForm
from merged.checkout.models import Order, OrderItem
from merged.checkout import checkout
from merged.cart import cart

from merged.accounts import profile

def show_checkout(request, template_name='checkout/checkout.html'):
    """ checkout form page to collect user shipping and billing information """
    if cart.is_empty(request):
        cart_url = urlresolvers.reverse('show_cart')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(cart_url)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = CheckoutForm(postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            response = checkout.process(request)
            order_number = response.get('order_number',0)
            error_message = response.get('message','')
            if order_number:
                request.session['order_number'] = order_number
                receipt_url = urlresolvers.reverse('checkout_receipt')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(receipt_url)
        else:
            error_message = u'Correct the errors below'
    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user_profile = profile.retrieve(request)
            form = CheckoutForm(instance=user_profile)
        else:
            form = CheckoutForm()
    page_title = 'Checkout'
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def receipt(request, template_name='checkout/receipt.html'):
    """ page displayed with order information after an order has been placed successfully """
    order_number = request.session.get('order_number','')
    if order_number:
        order = Order.objects.filter(id=order_number)[0]
        order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
    else:
        cart_url = urlresolvers.reverse('show_cart')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(cart_url)
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception Value: Order matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 357
```

Full Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/subscribe/

Django Version: 1.7.3
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'user',
 'common',
 'issue',
 'cms',
 'merged',
 'merged.accounts',
 'merged.utils',
 'merged.cart',
 'merged.checkout',
 'merged.catalog',
 'import_export')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/byrd/visibleheroku/merged/templates/tags/navigation.html, error at line 17
   Order matching query does not exist.
   7 :                         <h1>


   8 :                             <a href="#"></a>


   9 :                         </h1>


   10 :                     </li>


   11 :                     <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="/"><span>Menu</span></a></li>


   12 :                 </ul>


   13 :                 <section class="top-bar-section">


   14 :                     <ul>


   15 :                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>


   16 : 


   17 :                         <li><a href=" {% url 'my_account' %} ">My Account</a></li>


   18 : 


   19 :                     </ul>


   20 : 


   21 :                     <ul>


   22 :     <li>


   23 :         {% if user.is_authenticated %}


   24 :             <a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}">Logout</a>


   25 :         {% else %}


   26 :             <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a>


   27 :             </li>


Traceback:
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/merged/catalog/views.py" in index
  16.     return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  25.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  178.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  148.             return self._render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.                 return template.render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  148.             return self._render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  444.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  551.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  415.             self._populate()
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  292.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  315.             self._populate()
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  292.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  315.             self._populate()
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  303.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  231.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py" in wrapper
  101.                     result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  97.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/merged/cart/views.py" in <module>
  5. from merged.checkout import checkout
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/merged/checkout/checkout.py" in <module>
  6. from merged.checkout import skipjack
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/merged/checkout/skipjack.py" in <module>
  6. order = Order.objects.latest('id').id + 1
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in latest
  502.         return self._earliest_or_latest(field_name=field_name, direction="-")
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _earliest_or_latest
  496.         return obj.get()
File "/Users/byrd/visibleheroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  357.                 self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /subscribe/
Exception Value: Order matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: You've only shown one urls.py here, but you haven't told us which one and you haven't shown the other three. Plus, you haven't shown the actual error and traceback you receive.

Comment: I've added everything.

Comment: No, you haven't, you've only posted two of the four urls files and still not told us what the first one is. But never mind, the traceback quite clearly says the problem is happening in line 6 of skipjack.py. Are you doing a query at module level there?

Comment: That was it, thank you. I was doing a query to find the last order number in the database. Removing that line solved the issue.

Comment: ohh man...as a coder, this is my dreaded moment, exact same issue but no solution in answers!! :(((((((